# avoid code duplication in C++

Tags: c++

I have something like this in one project:

```
device::getInfo()
{
    // call static instance of computer
    desktop::instance().getDetailedInfo()
    // do some work
}
```

I want to inherit from this class and reuse the code in a different project but I want to use a different object instance

```
device::getInfo()
{
    // call static instance of computer
    laptop::instance().getDetailedInfo()
    // do some work
}
```

What's the best way to achieve that? The only thing I can come up with is to use preprocessor directives.

Comment: what is `device` supposed to represent? sounds like it shouldn't be tightly bound to either a `desktop` or `laptop`. My intuition would be that `desktop` or `laptop` would be a type of `device`... not the other way around

Comment: Avoid Singleton...

Comment: This code only looks like c++, it contains several errors that make it uncompilable. I'm trying to draw conclusions from the code, but it's hard to distinguish between what's an error and what's an intention. Notably, is it normal that `getDetailedInfo()`'s return value is not used? Does it set some static or global state?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes getDetailedInfo() is used later on I just want to keep it as simple as possible to focus on the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to inherit from this class and reuse the code in a different project

...

> What's the best way to achieve that? The only thing I can come up with is to use preprocessor directives.

#### Solution 1

Override `device::getInfo()` in the derived class.

```
device_inherited::getInfo()
{
   laptop::instance().getDetailedInfo()
}
```

#### Solution 2

If `desktop` and `laptop` can be derived from a common base class, you can use a `virtual` function in `device` to get a reference to the appropriate class.

```
device::getInfo()
{
    get_destop_base().getDetailedInfo()
}

// virtual member function
desktop_base& device::get_desktop_base()
{
   return desktop::instance();
}
```

and

```
// virtual member function
desktop_base& device_inherited::get_desktop_base()
{
   return laptop::instance();
}
```

Comment: I have explored solution 2. but since instance() is static, it can't be virtual :(

Comment: @DavidGo, which function is `static`?

Comment: laptop::instance() and desktop::instance()

Comment: I'm thinking that I should use an instance of the common class computer::instance() and move getDetailedInfo into the common class

Comment: @DavidGo, `laptop::instance()` and `desktop::instance()` can be `static`. That would not cause a problem.

Comment: @DavidGo, yes to *move getDetailedInfo into the common class* but only as a pure `virtual` function that is implemented in `desktop` and `laptop`.